# Gigya Swift SDK: "Invalid request signature"

Tags: ios, swift, gigya

Using the SDK version 1.0.11 I get this error

`LoginSocialInteractor.loginWithSocial error: LoginApiError<GigyaAccountResponse>(error: Gigya.NetworkError.gigyaError(data: Gigya.GigyaResponseModel(statusCode: Gigya.ApiStatusCode.unknown, errorCode: 403003, callId: “32cbfb666d654cf8b8434f852908d1d1”, errorMessage: Optional(“Invalid request signature”), sessionInfo: nil, requestData: Optional(2027 bytes))), interruption: nil), socialProvider: google`

This happens after installing a new ipa when the privacy consents where invalidated but not accepted.

We don't understand why this is happening, but I guess that has something to do with some data saved on the UserDefaults or Keychain. It is happenig only for a social login for now with users already registered.

Someone has the same problem?

Comment: What is Gigya? Link? What code produces this error?

Comment: Its an SDK for authentication: https://developers.gigya.com

here is the doc about the social login: https://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/Swift+SDK

paragraph: "Login With A Specified Provider"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's happened because you try to login when the session exists.
Make sure you make a logout before you trying to login again.

You can check if session exists by `isLoggedIn` method, Example:

```
if(Gigya.sharedInstance().isLoggedIn()) {
   // session is exists.
}
```

Comment: Mark it as correct since I don't see anymore the bug